# Any one clarify regarding Avplayer playback controls

Tags: ios, avplayer

I created avplayer like this but controlls are not showing.can any one explain is there any playback controls are we need to create our custom playbacks.

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample2" ofType:@"mp4"];
_videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
_videoAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:_videoURL];
_videoDuration = (int)CMTimeGetSeconds(_videoAsset.duration);
_playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:_videoAsset];
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];

_playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
_playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height*0.2, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height*0.3);
[self.layer addSublayer:_playerLayer];
[_player play];
_isPlaying = YES;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:_playerItem];
```